# Is there a way to Compile Pascal program without having the compiler to print its info?

Tags: freepascal

I was wondering if there is a way to compile a pascal program without having the compiler print its information. For example, here is what gets printed after each compile operation:

"Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0 [2014/03/21] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2011 by Florian Klaempfl and others
Target OS: FreeBSD for x86-64
Compiling Prob2.pas
Assembling lcmprog
Linking Prob2
138 lines compiled, 0.1 sec"

I would like to compile without this information being printed...

Your help is appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

Closest thing I could find was [this](http://www.freepascal.org/docs-html/user/userap1.html) command line option:

```
-v<x>  Be verbose. <x> is a combination of the following letters:  
      e : Show errors (default)       0 : Show nothing (except errors)  
      w : Show warnings               u : Show unit info  
      n : Show notes                  t : Show tried/used files  
      h : Show hints                  c : Show conditionals  
      i : Show general info           d : Show debug info  
      l : Show linenumbers            r : Rhide/GCC compatibility mode  
      s : Show time stamps            q : Show message numbers  
      a : Show everything             x : Executable info (Win32 only)  
      b : Write file names messages   p : Write tree.log with parse tree  
          with full path              v : Write fpcdebug.txt with  
                                          lots of debugging info
```

The `i` option corresponds to the Compiler Information header.  I would try the `0` option, and work your way up from there.

Comment: Option -v0 returns:                                                Free Pascal Compiler version 2.6.0 [2014/03/21] for x86_64
Copyright (c) 1993-2011 by Florian Klaempfl and others

Comment: Bummer. I suppose you could redirect console output to /dev/null.

Comment: Actually I redirected the output into a dummy file and it works just fine. Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Use `-l-` or remove `-l` from your `fpc.cfg` (possible locations might be `/etc/fpc.cfg` or `~/.fpc.cfg`).

Edit: In addition -v0 might be needed.

Comment: I tried fpc -l- prog.pas, however the same message is printed :(

Comment: So it prints still the copyright? If yes, this is really stange, if not, try additionally -v0 to get rid of the other messages.

Comment: fpc.cfg can live in the project's source folder.
On Windows it can also live under FPC's bin folder alongside fpc.exe
In either case it should contain:
# Suppress the compiler logo/banner/copyright with "hyphen lowercase-L minus"
-l-